# Custom view for Entityform submission

Tags: entities

I have a simple Entityform where the user selects from a list of Profile2 user profiles (internal staff and external staff). In simpler terms, the user selects from a list of entities (ie. pick 3 from a list of 10).

The Profile2 user profiles are being shown on the form via an Entity reference view so you can see the name (from user profile), picture (from user profile), status (from Profile2 staff profile) etc. associated with the selected users.

Unfortunately, the submission confirmation and submission screens only show the entity name (User Profile) instead of the actual user profile details. Basically I see:

```
Submitted by There, Hello on Thu, 03/05/2015 - 10:53
Person Selection
External Staff
Internal Staff
```

What I want to show is:

```
(picture) Joe Schmoe, Washington
(picture) Alex Trebec, Montreal
```

Does anyone know how to alter the confirmation and submission pages to show more detail about the underlying Entity (and/or associated Entity)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would suggest.

1. Clone the built in View
2. In the Entityform Type edit form select your new View under Submission Views -> View for submissions reports
3. In your new View add relationship to Profile2 entity via the Entity Reference field on the Entityform
4. Now you can add any field from the Profile2 to the View.